# AWS EC2 Instance website not reachable outside AWS RDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, firewall, rdp

I have a running(Windows OS) Amazon EC2 instance.  I can access my site using localhost. However, I am not able to access the website from outside the AWS RDP. I am using Public DNS to access the website.

**Already Verified following points**

- In the security group, I have opened inbound traffic for HTTP & HTTPS both for all IPs.
- I can ping this instance from outside the RDP using the public DNS.
- Add Firewall inbound rules for allowing all traffic.

**Note**
My site just runs one time after restart the AWS instance and then not.

I am not sure, what else is missing which required to run **my site outside the AWS RDP**.

**Checked the following Points**

- In the security group, I have opened inbound traffic for HTTP & HTTPS both for all IPs.
- I can ping this instance from outside the RDP using the public DNS.
- Add Firewall inbound rules to allow all traffic

I want to run my site outside the AWS RDP.
But now my site just runs one time after restart the AWS instance.

**Site IIS Binding:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugpxd.png

**Site-Run in AWS RDP:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIHha.jpg

**Site not Run outside the AWS RDP:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRFcF.png

**AWS RDP server pinging successfully:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL0ul.png

**netstat HTTP:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnK4L.png

**netstat HTTPS:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9hom.png

Comment: Windows has its own firewall. Did you unlock it as well?

Comment: Yes, I have unlocked the firewall as well.

Comment: Which web server is used in the EC2 instance website?

Comment: I used a Microsoft web server Internet Information Services (IIS).

Comment: Maybe related to [this error](https://serverfault.com/questions/955948/iis-7-5-working-only-from-localhost). More generally this is the kind of issue you'd have on Linux if your app listens on 127.0.0.1 (loopback) instead of 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces).

Comment: could you please share what is your iis server site binding and what error or warning you are seeing in the browser when you access the site?

Comment: I have shared the site binding information, which includes the IP address, port, and host name used for the IIS server site. Additionally, I've provided details on the errors or warnings that are displayed in the browser when accessing the site. You can view this information in my question. If you have any further questions or need more details, please let me know.

Comment: could just run this command to get the domain configuration detail:`nslookup example.com`. also add another site bindings with the * and http with port number 80 and access teh site outside with public ip for test purpose

Answer (score 2):

You covered your initial bases. Here's what I would personally do next:

On the webserver, check to see if IIS is listening on ports 443 and 80. Because you're able to access it locally, it is - but it may only be listening on loopback. One easy way to check this is using netstat. You can do this for HTTPS via:

```
netstat -anot | findstr :443 | findstr LISTENING
```

and for HTTP via:

```
netstat -anot | findstr :80 | findstr LISTENING
```

Look to see if the left column (next to TCP) shows the server **only** listening on the loopback 127.0.0.1 address. You'll want it to listen on 0.0.0.0 or the IP of the machine.

[image]

If it is listening, I would run a packet capture in Wireshark (if possible) on the machine to confirm that the TCP SYN is making it to you. You can use a display filter like "tcp.port==443 or tcp.port==80 or icmp" to assist in this testing. Ping the server, you should see an ICMP echo and reply. Then try an HTTP connection and see if the traffic is reaching your server. From there, you can pinpoint where the breakdown is (IE: Traffic isn't reaching you or it is, if it's not look upstream)

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: I have added the netstat for both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: So, your netstat appears good - you're listening on 443 and 80 on all available interfaces (0.0.0.0).

I would try testing with Wireshark to see if the packet is making it to you or not.

Also, I see that you're running FileZilla as an FTP server on that host. I'm not able to ping your server, or hit it via HTTP or HTTPS - but I can reach the FTP server:

ftp test.signaturewebmedical.com
Connected to test.signaturewebmedical.com.
220-FileZilla Server 0.9.59 beta

You might try comparing port 21 in your ACLs to the HTTP/HTTPS rules.